# Mongo convert foreignField object to string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There are many example out there where they convert the `localField` variable to a string from an object like so.

```
dbo.collection('exampleCollection').aggregate{[
{
    $lookup: {
          from:'User_List',
          localField:'id',
          foreignField:'_id', //how do I convert the foreignField Object to string?
          as:'whatever'
        }
    }]
}
```

These are the collections.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to convert the `foreignField` variable to a string? This part is crucial to me as it's the only part of the query I am missing.
Thank you in advance people!

Comment: Please show some sample documents from both the collections

Comment: @Ashh I added two collections as an example. Let me know if this clarify it. Please have in mind that this is not the full query so I cannot aggregate to User_List by looking up exampleCollection (essentially, doing stuff the other way around)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation

```
dbo.collection("exampleCollection").aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "User_List",
    "let": { "id": "$id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$toString": "$_id" }, "$$id"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "whatever"
  }}
])
```

Comment: did you test that?

Comment: No. But I can write this queries roughly.

Comment: I have tried same, and not seems working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually instead of converting the foreingField to a string, convert the localField to a string so you can compare object to object.

A sample code is as follows:

```
{$lookup:{
     from:'User_List',
     let:{resultObj:{$toObjectId:'$result'}},
     pipeline:
     [{
         $match:{
             $expr:{$eq:['$_id','$$resultObj']}
         }
     }],
     as:'whatever'
  }
}
```

I apologize if it looks dirty. I am still getting used to mongo and how to properly indent.